# What's that equation that spells a math word?

Tags: graphing-functions

I can't remember what it was, but I vaguely remember a semi-famous equation that when graphed spells a math word like "equation" or a number, does anyone know what that is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you may be looking for [Tupper's self-referential formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupper%27s_self-referential_formula) :

$$ \frac{1}{2} < \left\lfloor\text{mod}\left( \left\lfloor \frac{y}{17} \right\rfloor 2^{-17\lfloor x\rfloor - \text{mod}(\lfloor y\rfloor, 17)} , 2\right)\right\rfloor$$

This formula plots any bitmap of 105 by 16 in the range $0 \le x \le 16$ and $k\le y\le k+16$, indexed by $k$.

For a particular 543-digit number, it plots itself (upside down), but there exists a $k$ such as it plots *equation*, *number* or anything else you'd want to see.

Comment: Is there any practical use for this kind of equation? Like does anyone use it for communications or computer graphics or anything like that?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I vaguely recall that $k$ is actually a simple encoding of the bitmap drawing, so it would be way more efficient to just send $k$ and decode it manually.